# Using regular expressions to validate a range of numeric values delimiter by semicolon

Tags: regex, string

I need a regular expression to validate a string of the format, **using Javascript**:

> 119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,2,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185

My Regexp https://regex101.com/r/nhFnKE/1

the problem is that there may be ranges like "n - x"

> 0-1,2,3,4-7,8,9-20,21

Thank you very much for your help

PS: space management and repeated I will do it in another instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might match a repeated pattern with one or more digits with an optional part ? that matches a dash and one or more digits followed by a comma or the end of the line `$`

[`^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,|$))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/PopACr/1)

Or repeat the optional part `(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,)*` zero or more times including the comma and make sure that the last match is `\d+(?:-\d+)?`

[`^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,)*\d+(?:-\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PopACr/2)

```js
const strings = [
  "119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,2,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185,119,122,178-181,185",
  "0-1,2,3,4-7,8,9-20,21",
  "0-1,2,test"
];
let pattern = /^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,)*\d+(?:-\d+)?$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(pattern.test(s));
});
```